# Which is right to use? flash[:notice] vs :notice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Which one is right to use? `flash[:notice] = 'some msg'` or `:notice = 'some msg'`?

I have met both options, but there is no explanations about difference. So I confused which one is right to use. Maybe it's the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a controller with an action, such as the following:

```
def create
  @activity = Activity.new activity_params
  if @activity.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Activity was successfully created!'
    redirect_to activity_path(@activity)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Then you can use `flash[:notice]` and set the `flash` hash's notice to `Activity was successfully created!`.

However, you are correct, when using `redirect_to` you can pass `:notice` as an option, as such:

```
def destroy
  if @activity.destroy
    redirect_to activities_path, notice: 'Activity was successfully destroy!'
  else
    flash.now[:notice] = 'Activity was not destroyed.'
  end
end
```

If you check the [ActionController::Redirecting module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) you will see that notice can be passed as an option.

Fundamentally, these two things do the same thing. They are just being set differently.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that `redirect_to` only supports `alert`, `notice` and `flash`. It doesn't support `success` and others. Notice is also stored inside a variable called `notice`. So you don't have to use the `flash` object to access it.